# how to make javascript total load into a hidden input box?

Tags: php, javascript, text, input

How can I make javascript load into a hidden input box?

I have `<span id="number"></span>` which pulls from java to give me the total number...

I want to use something like -

`<input type="hidden" name="number" id="number" />`

my javascript code - which makes number appear -

```
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

I know php somewhat well but javascript i am weak i have forgetton alot...

Comment: Did you try this? any issues? Usually .value will be used instead of .innerHTML when it is of type input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  document.getElementById("number").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
```